# Scrapy call javascript function

Tags: javascript, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy to crawl this website : http://egypuppy.com/e-store.php?fl=1

In the drop down menu by the right, I can choose a breed to view the dogs, this is an example for one of the li elements in the drop down menu :

> href="javascript:getDogForSale('0','1');setBreedName('Affenpinscher');"
>   id="no-image"

is there a way to call this JS function using scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy does not natively support rendering JavaScript so you need to roll your own solution, but this work involves multiple [Reactors](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQjBAwBA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern&ei=YnJUUZv-AYabyQHW14CIBw&usg=AFQjCNGZAaoSclV4agIMribyMAOdYKFEuw&sig2=X9_fnnqQfr_qU_RRNwCaSA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aWc) which is not programmed by the faint of heart.

Here are some integration options:

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)
- [SpiderMonkey](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey)
- [WebKit](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebKit)